# how to get value from textbox and look after it in mysql then print it if vail?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some issues here and I cannot solve it , I want to get value from text box and display it if its available in mysql
what am I currently doing :
index.php

```
    <form method="get" action="code.php">
    <input name="code" type="text">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

and as for my code.php

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","code");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Code , Status FROM data");


 //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   //{
   //echo $row['$_GET ""'] . " " . $row['Status'];
   //echo "<br />";
   //}

if(isset($_GET['Code']))
{
    $Code=$_REQUEST['Code'];
    $Status=$_REQUEST['Status'];

    echo $Code; /* no value is echo */
    echo $Status; /* no value is echo */
}    


 mysqli_close($con);


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of case-sensitivity. You sent data named `code`, not `Code`. Also you don't have any field named `Status` in your form so I have now idea what are you expecting with it.

Comment: still not woeking . shold I delete this ?

Comment: if(isset($_GET['Code']))
{
    $Code=$_REQUEST['Code'];
    $Status=$_REQUEST['Status'];

    echo $Code; /* no value is echo */
    echo $Status; /* no value is echo */
}    
should I delete ?

Comment: delete `$Status...` lines and change both `['Code']` to `['code']`.